# Queues configured for YARN dynamic resource pool or not?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, cloudera-manager

I am new to cloudera. I am using cloudera manager console 5.4.

Under dynamic resource pool, I find two tabs status and configuration.

In status, I see various queues under resource pool usage. However I can't edit info over there.

And in configuration, I find no queues configured, only default queue.

Can you please tell me whether queues are configured or not?

Answer (score 0):

In Cloudera Manager, go to the "Web UI" tab and click on "Resource Manager Web UI ...".  Then on the RM web UI, click on the left side bar link for "Scheduler".

If your queues are created, you should see them there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I see queues in resource manager WebUI under scheduler section. Wonder why it doesn't show in configuration section under dynamic resource pools. Please suggest.

Comment: I restarted resourcemanager and it reflected modified values everywhere.